# javascript - different behaviour on page refresh

Tags: javascript

I have a really weird problem.
I have a site (running wordpress), and I use jquery roundabout plugin.

When I visit the site with the address bar, the site is displayed fine. When I'm already in the site and I hit refresh - everything is messed up. I checked in both chrome and firefox, and I get the same result. In IE there is no problem.
Also, I noticed that the problem occurs only when doing a soft refresh (F5) and it's ok when doing a hard refresh (Ctrl+F5)

You can check for yourself in my test site
http://50.112.34.111
try to press enter in the address bar a few times - should display ok. try to refresh - and you'll see the problem...

Comment: What is 'displayed fine'?  The two scenarios I get are: grey box in the top-right and two grey boxes overlapped.  In my browser, the problem seems random, rather than due to the type of refresh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I would try to put the JS includes (`<script.../>`) in the header AFTER all CSS includes! That might already help. Since the CSS might influence your JS, JS has to know all CSS before it gets loaded.

Comment: Best use is btw to put all JS at the end of your HTML - just right before the closing </html> tag. There are exceptions, though - for example if you use the well known modernizr.js, it has to come right in the head part of your files (but also there _after_ all CSS declarations). Every single file referenced/loaded in the header part of your document delays the rendering/display of your page in the visitor's browser (which is not the case if you put your js includes at the end of the document).